# Minimum Sum, Revisited. (Not Minimum Subarray Sum)

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

Given a number n, an array arr I will like to pull the smallest number of integers to reach n, and also remove the numbers I used from arr. It is better explained with an example. Given n = 13 and arr = [8,0,2,2,3,1,1,3,1] I have to remove the smallest number of integers from arr that will sum up to 13.

My strategy is to sort arr in decreasing order, arr will hence be [8,3,3,2,2,1,1,1,0], then I start iterating from the first to the last number and break out when I reach n, 13 in this case. Given our example, I will end with 8,3,3 since it I will be at 13 already. But here comes the problem, Just behind 3 is 2 and I will be saving more if I choose 2 instead of 3 (8 + 3 + 2 = 13). I say saving more because this problem is part of another huge problem and to implement it successfully, I need to get the minimum possible. If at the place of two, I had say 5, my sorting method will have been just fine. And also, I will like to remove the numbers I used to get the sum and keep them in another array, call it a arr1. SO for this example, the result should be arr = [3,2,1,1,1,0] and arr1 = [8,3,2]. Can Anyone help me Please? My Python Code Looks something like this (assuming the list is already sorted):

```
n = 13

arr1 = []

arr = [8,3,3,2,2,1,1,1,0]

for i in xrange(len(arr)):

     if sum(arr1) < n:

          arr1.append(arr[0])

          del arr[0]

     else:

          break

print arr,arr1
```

This will print [2,2,1,1,1,0] [8,3,3]. But I would like it to print [8,3,2] [3,2,1,1,1]

Comment: maximum value of number?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
n = 13

arr1 = []

arr = [8,3,3,2,2,1,1,1,0]

for i in arr:
     if sum(arr1)+i <= n:
          arr1.append(i)
          arr.remove(i)
     if sum(arr1) == n:
          break
print arr,arr1
```